# How to fix a database that stores information in a comma delimited fashion

Tags: mysql, database

I am currently working on a project which was developed a number of years back. It is a `PHP` web application that uses `MySQL` database. The developer did it in such a way that certain columns of the database store data in a comma seperated way. For instance:

A Company can have MANY tags and a tag can have MANY companies. Rather than storing the data in an intermediate table with the company id and the tag id the developer stores the name of each tag in the company table under the tag column seperated by a comma.

I've been tasked with reformatting the search functionality of the system and hopefully will be able to speed up the queries. This method of storing the data immediately jumped out at me because it seems impractical.

I'm just wondering if I could get advice on how you might approach this issue? The database is quite large but that is no excuse for not including the intermediate tables in the first place. Am I right in thinking the best way to go about this is to create the tables for the many to many relationships and modifying the existing logic to utilise these tables?

I'm only a Junior developer but I am trying to get this done properly and would appreciate any advice on the task. It is my understanding that storing data in this fashion can slow down the query performance and make it a lot harder to work with the data.

EDIT: If this question is better suited in the "Programmers" Exchange I will move it. I didn't realise until after I posted the question such a site existed.

Comment: Yes. The rest of this comment can be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

If you know have the list of all existing tags in a table named Tag, here is how you can create the CompanyTag table:

```
CREATE TABLE CompanyTag
(
 SELECT company.Id AS CompanyId, tag.Id AS TagId
 FROM Company company
  INNER JOIN Tag tag ON company.Tags REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', tag.Id, '[[:>:]]')
);
```

The REGEXP '[[:<:]]...[[:>:]]' expression matches values separated by "word boundaries".
See also: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

For example, if Company contains rows (Id,Tags)

```
(1, 40,41)
(2, 30)
```

And Tag contains rows (Id)

```
(30)
(40)
(41)
```

Then CompanyTag will be created with (CompanyId,TagId)

```
(1, 40)
(1, 41)
(2, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at scripting the comma-delimited columns into their ordinate columns and then normalizing the database?